# Is there a way to ensure a specific visual studio project in a visual studio solution is only built on a build server (or a specific server)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, continuous-integration, xamarin-studio

Basically I want to block developers from building one of the projects in a solution that only the build server can/should build.

Alternatively, Developers would have a solution with projects A, B, C but not D. However, The build server would add project D to the solution. Then build the solution with projects A,B,C, & D.

Can this be done through code and/or configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Your "project" is a bunch of plaintext files containing code. How in the world will you prevent developers copying this code wherever they want? Theoretically you can develop a whole crypto system, encrypting your sources and a crypto-compiler, decrypting the sources on the fly and compiling given the correct key. But I doubt you will do this.

Comment: If you don't want them to be able to build it, don't give them access to the source control, and they won't be able to build it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You don't need to go *that* far, you just only give the developers the already-compiled code (built on the build server), rather than the source code.

Comment: @Servy Given it is an XY-problem - yes.

Comment: You can make a command line Make file and add restrictions in the make file.

Comment: @jdweng What will prevent "developers" from modifying the makefile?

Comment: Make it read/execute only only with and set to run with admin privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one of possible solution would be creating different [build configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx). Each build configuration would include projects needed to run properly.

Simplified example:

Developers could use default `Debug` configuration to build projects A, B and C (D must be excluded from this configuration) to run application locally.

`Production` configuration would have all projects (A, B, C and D) included, and your continuous integration system would use that configuration to build your solution.

Keep in mind what others said, you **won't** be able to *protect* project D from manual or accidental builds, as long as it stays inside same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not really - if code is available it can be built by developers. One can create project file from source and build it to be able to debug the code for example.

You can use NuGet to import pre-built assemblies - this way you discourage building such code locally.

Note: make sure you understand reasons why one would want to build that code locally - debugging is very common reason and degrading debugging experience will slow your team down.